# Pass a multiline text block as MediaWiki template parameter

Tags: templates, parameters, mediawiki

I wish to make a collapse template to hide a block of text and show it by clicking on expand.
I found such code as follows

```
<div class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed" style="background-color: #E6E6E6; border-style: thin black; font-style:italic; ">
<p><i>Try it by yourself before expanding on the right!</i></p>
<div class="mw-collapsible-content">
some text or wiki encoded text content (better for formatings and images)
that will remain hidden
until expand is clicked
</div>
</div>
```

which I tried to make a template for (Collapse)

```
<div class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed" style="background-color: #E6E6E6; border-style: thin black; font-style:italic; ">
<p><i>Try it by yourself before expanding on the right!</i></p>
<div class="mw-collapsible-content">
{{{1}}}
</div>
</div>
```

My currently failing call would be

```
{{Collapse|some text or wiki encoded text content (better for formatings and images)
    that will remain hidden
    until expand is clicked}}
```

but I do not succeed to pass the input text block using {{{1}}} because my content is full of line feeds and other formatting tags.

Do I need to act in the template or in the call to wrap and with which tag?
any help welcome.

Comment: “but I do not succeed” What exactly does happen? What is the actual result and how is it different from the expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need create two templates:

```
{{Collapse Begin}}
```

With contents:

```
<div class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed" style="background-color: #E6E6E6; border-style: thin black; font-style:italic; ">
<p><i>Try it by yourself before expanding on the right!</i></p>
<div class="mw-collapsible-content">
```

And:

```
{{Collapse End}}
```

With contents:

```
</div>
</div>
```

And then on pages add:

```
{{Collapse Begin}}
some text or wiki encoded text content (better for formatings and images)
that will remain hidden
until expand is clicked
{{Collapse End}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, naming the parameters allows using multiline input (do not ask me why!).

The following code does the job for me but thank you **ankap** for the smart idea, I will reuse it somewhere else.

I added an optional margin to indent the coloured box when used in lists and a separate parameters for the message shown in collapsed-mode.

```
<!-- takes tup to three parameters
* margin: to indent the block in the page, useful if the collapse is within a bullet list
* comment: to show a warning on the expand line
* content: the actual content to hide
# adding additional div improved support for lists etc...
-->
<div class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed" style="background-color: #E6E6E6; 
border-style: thin black; font-style:italic; margin-left: {{{margin|0px}}}; ">
<includeonly><i>{{{comment|<nowiki>
Try it by yourself before expanding on the right!</nowiki>}}}</i><includeonly>
<div class="mw-collapsible-content"><div>{{{content|{{{1}}}}}}</div></div>
</div>
```

enjoy!